# How to apply freestyle on only one mesh?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, freestyle

I have a scene in Blender in which I want to apply freestyle effects to just one object. Is this possible. How can I do it?
(I'm using Cycles)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the freestyle settings, check the "collection" option for selection by, then you can add your one object to a collection, and choose that collection in the settings menu below.

[image: free]